# How to get a variable from inside a string

Tags: c#, regex, string, substring

I'm trying to pull out a `BookingID` from inside an email.

The email will always contain the below text but the `BookingID` will always be different.

> WEB BOOKING ID NUMBER: 12345678

I have tried the below but it just gives me the BookingID + the rest of the email after it.

```
string search = "WEB BOOKING ID NUMBER: ";
string bookingID = myItem.Body.Text.Substring(myItem.Body.Text.IndexOf(search) + search.Length);
```

Note that the `BookingID` will always be the same length (8 characters).

I would greatly appreciate some help on this.

Comment: Use string split : string input = "WEB BOOKING ID NUMBER: 12345678";
            string output = input.Split(new char[] { ':' }).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().Trim();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
var search = @"WEB BOOKING ID NUMBER:\s*([0-9]+)";
var match = Regex.Match(myItem.Body.Text, search);
var res = string.Empty;
if (match.Success) 
{
    res = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

The `WEB BOOKING ID NUMBER:\s*([0-9]+)` pattern will find `WEB BOOKING ID NUMBER:` text followed with 0+ whitespace chars (`\s*`) and will capture into Group 1 one or more digits (`([0-9]+)`).

See the [regex demo here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=WEB%20BOOKING%20ID%20NUMBER%3A%5Cs*%28%5B0-9%5D%2B%29&i=WEB%20BOOKING%20ID%20NUMBER%3A%2012345678%2C%20and%20more%20text%20here):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the [second argument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) to the `Substring` function to limit the length of the extracted part:

```
const string search = "WEB BOOKING ID NUMBER: ";
var bookingID = myItem.Body.Text.Substring(myItem.Body.Text.IndexOf(search) + search.Length, 8);
```